# Поиск определенных значений в тексте

Tags: java, сортировка, поиск, hashmap

Прошу подсказать удобный метод для  поиска слов/значений в тексте.

Есть  hashMap c ключом и значением это код страны RU и значение Россия <String,String>
Мне нужно проверить большой текст на наличие в нем Кодов стран , которые содержатся  в  hashMap.
Например , если в тексте есть RU DE ZB , то нужно вывести их и отобразит.
Идея такая , что нужно брать каждый элемент (код) из hashMap и искать его в тексте , если он есть , добавляем его значение (полное название страны) в коллекцию и так до конца и  так до конца , пока не
не закончится текст.

После того, когда я заполнил мапу значениями:

```
 @Test
    Map<String,String> contextLoads() {
        
        String[] countries = Locale.getISOCountries();
         
         var arr = new ArrayList<Countries>(countries.length);
         
        var hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        for(Countries o : arr) {
            
            hm.put(o.getCode(), o.getName());
                        
        }
        
        return hm;
        }
```

Далее , создал метод , который посоветовали в комментариях, чтобы найти в тексте
коды стран и вывести их:

```
@Test
    void contextShow(String text, Map m) {
        
        String t = "if(panContry=='DE')";
    m=contextLoads();
        
        String reg =String.format("^|[ (])(%s)($|[\\s.!?,)])", String.join("|", m.keySet()));
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
        Matcher mat = p.matcher(t);
        
        
        Set<String> countries =new HashSet<>();
               

        while (mat.find()) {
            countries.add((String) m.get(mat.group(2)));
        }

       for(String c : countries) {
           System.out.println(c);
       }
```

Ошибка при выполнении:

```
  org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.lang.String text] in method [void com.statusinfonew.springboot.SpringBootStatusinfoApplicationTests.contextShow(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)].
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:200)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:144)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:96)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Уточите , в чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: Можно с другой стороны зайти. Пробежаться пр тексту и запеленговать только коды стран. И потом по результатам найти пересечение двух множеств

Answer (score 1):

Ну, если немного поупарываться, то так:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "lalala RU bla bla RU. DE la al UK";

    Map<String, String> codes = new HashMap<>();
    codes.put("RU", "Russia");
    codes.put("DE", "Germany");
    codes.put("UK", "United Kingdom");

    String reg = String.format("(^|[ (])(%s)($|[\s.!?,)])", String.join("|", codes.keySet()));
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    Set<String> countries = new HashSet<>();

    while (m.find()) {
        countries.add(codes.get(m.group(2)));
    }

    countries.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

В такой задаче регулярные выражения жизненно необходимы, чтобы не учитывать случаи, когда нужная последовательность символов является частью какого-то слова, но учитывать её в начале/конце текста, вместе с запятой, в скобочках и тд.

String.format() тут нужен, чтобы подставить страны из мапы в выражение.

Что по поводу принципа работы... По моей логике, перед кодом страны может находиться начало строки, открывающая скобка или пробел. За это отвечает `(^|[ (])` данная часть выражения. Обычно для выбора одного любого символа из какого-то списка используют [] квадратные скобки, но с таким методом у меня возникли проблемы с символом начала строки ^ и с открывающей скобкой, которые либо автоматически экранировались, где не надо, либо не экранировались там, где надо. Поэтому я использовал конструкцию (элемент|элемент|элемент), она сработала, как запланировано.

Потом после выполнения подстановки у меня идет такая часть: `(RU|DE|UK)`. Здесь я использую |, так как мне требует именно сочетание двух букв, а не любой из символов.

После кода страны по логике должен следовать знак препинания, пробел, закрывающая скобка или конец строки, за что и отвечает эта `($|[\s.!?,)])` часть выражения. Опять использую |, потому что возникали проблемы с экранированием символа $.

Comment: Спасибо! Не имел дело с такой обработкой  m.find(),  m.group(2) , он будет добавлять в мапу те коды , которые содержатся в тексте , неважно , с какими символами они(коды стран) рядом стоят  ?

Comment: String reg = String.format("^|[ (])(%s)($|[\s.!?,)])", String.join("|", codes.keySet()));  вот это строчку , уточните пожалуйста , как она работает ? Несилен в регулярных выражениях

Comment: Да, круглые скобки формируют группу, к которой можно обратиться по индексу. Группа с индексом 0 всегда возвращает всё найденное выражение. Другие же индексы содержат только ту часть регулярного выражения, которая находится в скобках с этим индексом.

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня потерялась одна скобка в выражении, уже поправил.

Comment: если коды стран будут находится в кавычках "RU" , то он также его найдет ?

Comment: Нет, кавычки я не учитывал. Их необходимо учесть отдельно.